# Converting URI -> object -> imagesource

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

```
img = new Image()
{
    Height = 150,
    Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill,
    Width = 200
};
img.Source = (ImageSource) new ImageSourceConverter()
                .ConvertFromString("/FirstDemo;component/Images/Hero.jpg");
```

After hours of research, trying to assign an image to an image class.
I came across this way of assigning an image.
I have absolutely no idea why I this code does not run.
It does not get any compiler error though.. Odd.
its 11 25 pm here btw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
img = new Image();
img.Height = 150;
img.Width = 200;
img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/FirstDemo;component/Images/Hero.jpg"));
```

Comment: Awesome good to hear. If you can mark it as an aswer do it, but if you do not have enough reputation do not forget to do so whaen you do.

Answer (score 2):

Your URI string is probably broken, see [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for more detail on how it should be composed (you might be missing `"pack://application:,,,"` at the beginning).

In any case you should usually not use the `ImageSourceConverter` in code, it is intended for the XAML parser.

Instead use [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx):

```
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
```